# Transition only working on debug

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

The following code only works when I debug through it:

```js
function testFunction()
{
  var input = document.getElementById("testInput");
  var button = document.getElementById("testButton");
  
  input.style.transition = "box-shadow 0s";
  input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 5px #ff0000";
  input.style.transition = "box-shadow 5s";
  input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px #000000";
  //input.focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="testInput"/>
<button id="testButton" onclick="testFunction();">Press me!</button>
```

I tried it without `input.focus();` but that doesn't make a difference. When my debugger is at this point `input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 5px #ff0000";` I can continue and it works. Why isn't my input field red outlined when I run this code? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqt4dehg/3/).

Comment: Without perhaps the console output, it's hard to say.

I'll look at JSFiddle and see if there is anything specific missing, as you only gave me a block of code.

Comment: @4g0tt3nSou1 The console doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you set 2 transitions synchronously one after another, the browser optimizes it and renders they in the one frame. You could set a small duration (for example, `1ms`) to the first transition and use [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event:

```js
function testFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("testInput");
    var button = document.getElementById("testButton");

    input.style.transition = "box-shadow 1ms";
    input.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
        input.style.transition = "box-shadow 5s";
        input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px #000000";
    }, false);
    input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 5px #ff0000";
    //input.focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="testInput"/>
<button id="testButton" onclick="testFunction();">Press me!</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/pcdxrdju/2/)

Also could use the old hack with [setTimeout(fn, 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) to make it works:

```js
function testFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("testInput");
    var button = document.getElementById("testButton");

    input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 5px #ff0000";
    setTimeout(function() {
        input.style.transition = "box-shadow 5s";
        input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px #000000";
    }, 0);
    //input.focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="testInput"/>
<button id="testButton" onclick="testFunction();">Press me!</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/hau4040g/)

Answer (score 0):

You add an additional line to set a 0px black `box-shadow`, and yet you expect a red shadow..

Take a look at the updated jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wqt4dehg/4/

```js
function testFunction()
{
 var input = document.getElementById("testInput");
  var button = document.getElementById("testButton");
  
  input.style.transition = "box-shadow 0s";
  input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 5px #ff0000";
  input.style.transition = "box-shadow 5s";
  //input.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px #000000";
  //input.focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="testInput"/>
<button id="testButton" onclick="testFunction();">Press me!</button>
```

Comment: I want to fade the red border away.